# Atmel software framework API

Tags: atmel-studio, cortex-m0

Okay, so here I am starting to get acquainted with SAMD series MCUs from Atmel and initially I just want to use ASF APIs and get one project done, however I thought ASF provides APIs for every piece of configuration.
I saw this in datasheet.

[image]

However the only option ASF provides is

[image]

So like what should I do to select last config i.e. OUTPUT;Input Enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `port_pin_dir` to `PORT_PIN_DIR_OUTPUT_WTH_READBACK`

[ASF: SAM D20/D21/R21 Port Driver (PORT)](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/3.16.0/samd21/html/group__asfdoc__sam0__port__group.html#gabe12893c067f9b011ece79c1bf1b128a)

> PORT_PIN_DIR_OUTPUT_WTH_READBACK
>
> The pin's output and input buffers should be enabled, so that the pin
>   state can be set and read back.

Comment: and do you know what is the base address of port peripheral, it's really hard to find in datasheet.

Comment: 0x41004400 (SAM D20 datasheet page 24. Figure 8-1. Product Mapping).

Comment: ohh silly me...